# Redirecting to subfolder while displaying root URL with .htaccess language redirect and manual language selector

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Apologies in advance for contributing to what must already be an exhaustive list of questions related to .htaccess redirects. My question concerns a client website consisting of multiple language versions, the folder structure being as follows:

```
index.html (default german version)
— en
  index.html
— fr
  index.html
— nl
  index.html
– css
– img
– js
```

Said client now asked me to implement a language redirect which I did by **moving the default german version to its own subfolder** and placing the following `.htaccess` in the **root directory**.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to dutch language version
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^(nl.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /nl/ [L,R=302]

# Redirect to french language version
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^(fr.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /fr/ [L,R=302]

# Redirect to english language version
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^(en.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=302]

# Redirect all other languages to english language version
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} !^(nl|fr|de|en).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=302]

# Redirect to german language version
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-language} ^(de.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [L,R=302]
```

The redirects themselves work as they should and don’t conflict with the manual language selector on each respective page. The only problem I am left with is that the URL shown in the browser includes the subfolder for the respective language, i.e:

```
mydomain.com/de/
mydomain.com/en/
mydomain.com/fr/
mydomain.com/nl/
```

While this is **intended for the non-default languages** (i.e. en, fr and nl), the URL should show the **root address when visiting the default german version**:

```
mydomain.com
instead of
mydomain.com/de/
```

How would I need to modify my `.htaccess`file to achieve the desired behavior? I am testing the site from within a subfolder on the sites server called `dev` so the suggested solution should ideally work with `mydomain.com` and `dev.mydomain.com` alike.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: You are _only_ redirecting when the requested URL path was `/` … So if you leave the German version in the main folder, and don’t do any redirecting for requested language `de` - then what would actually still be missing?

Comment: @CBroe If I leave the German version in the main folder, the language redirect would keep sending a visitor who has his browser language set to English and tries to access the German version via the manual language selector back to the English version. If there is a way to restrict the redirect to only requests NOT coming from either of the language subfolders, maybe that would work, too?

Comment: Well then you need to stop redirecting externally for the German version, and make that an internal rewrite only. Plus you will probably need to add some check what the current URL is, to avoid a redirect loop.